# Integration Oracle Cloud Kafka + Elastic-agent doesn't work

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, logstash, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Good afternoon. At the moment, there was an attempt to connect to collect logs from Oracle cloud Audit logs via Kafka, and everything worked through logstash. Now when I try to use Custom Kafka Integration in elasticsearch I get an error.

Logstash conf

```
\`
kafka {
bootstrap_servers =\> "server:9092"
topics =\> \["topic"\]
security_protocol =\> "SASL_SSL"
sasl_mechanism =\> "PLAIN"
jaas_path =\> "{PATH TO CONFIG}"
auto_offset_reset =\> "earliest"
consumer_threads =\> 1
}
}\``
```

JAAS

```
`\`#           KafkaClient {
org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
username="tenant/username/streampool}}"
password="";
};\``
```

It's worked ok.

And when we use this is config for elastic-agent, it doesn't work

I'am use this is username and password and use kafka consumer group "elastic" and get error message

```
Error initializing kafka consumer group

kafka: couldn't fetch broker metadata (check that your client and broker are using the same encryption and authentication settings)
```

Also I try used port 9092 and get error Error initializing kafka consumer group

```
kafka: client has run out of available brokers to talk to (Is your cluster reachable?)
```